# How to share calendar events with entire organisation using Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: exchange, calendar

We as an organisation use MS Exchange as our email/calendar service. Events of interest to us are things like conferences in the commodities space like iron ore, etc.

There are a number of these events annually across the world. Is there some feature where a calendar can be filled with events and then shared with the entire organisation?

Or is this as simple as creating a user with those events and then just subscribing to that user's calendar?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an Exchange answer or capabilities, then yes having a shared mailbox or Public Folder calendar open to everyone is a good solution.

Another solution might be to use a portal product like SharePoint. It has the capabilities to share calendars and it can even link into Exchange mailboxes if that is somethign you want to do.

Both options are open to you. The cheaper of the two is to use the product you already know: Exchange.